# The most important web application vulnerabilities

Tags: security, web, xss, sql-injection

As the matter of web applications vulnerabilities is one of the most important issues in the today's security problems/threats , so I'm interested in knowing what kind of such vulnerabilities are the most important one.
Indeed, which one of them have been affecting websites in recently years ?
So thanks.

Comment: this question has its place on **http://security.stackexchange.com**

Comment: @elsadek Oh really sorry but I'm new on this website, there is no way to answer here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@elsadek suggestion is good. This is a partial answer to your big question. Some of what comes to mind is below but hte list is not enclusive by any means...):

1-Injection (SQL and/or JSON pair injection)

2-Cross site scripting (XSS)

3-Broken Authentication & Session Management

4-Insecure Direct Object Reference

5-Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)

6-Security Misconfig

7-Insecure Cryptography Storage

8-Failiure to restrict URL Access

9-Insufficint Tansport Layer Protection

10-Unvalidated redirects and forwards

11-Deniel of service attacks

12-Log spoofing

13-JS Hijacking

14-Buffer overflow

15-Bad security administration and security policy regarding passwords specification and update

Some others are listed here for example: [10 Security Holes](http://www.net-security.org/article.php?id=956&p=1).